# ASP.NET: Using MVC partial view in web forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a regular ASP.NET web form page and am pasting in a `<%= Html.Partial(...) %>` that I took from an MVC view page.

What do I need to do to this web forms .aspx to get the Html.Partial to work? I've put this at the top of my web forms .aspx page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
```

But I'm still getting error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the error because `Html` is a property of the `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` class and is an instance of the `HtmlHelper` class. The `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` class is the class that your default ASP.NET MVC views inherit from, so you have access to the `Html` property in your views.

I don't know how you would go about creating an `HtmlHelper` instance in your webforms page but I would imagine that you'd have a hard time because it's constructor takes a `ViewContext` and an `IViewDataContainer`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article about how to use MVC in webforms: http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc